# Java 8 lambda get and remove element from list

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of elements, I want to get the element with a given property **and** remove it from the list. The best solution I found is:

```
ProducerDTO p = producersProcedureActive
                .stream()
                .filter(producer -> producer.getPod().equals(pod))
                .findFirst()
                .get();
producersProcedureActive.remove(p);
```

Is it possible to combine get and remove in a lambda expression?

Comment: This really seems like a classic case of when to just use a loop and iterator instead.

Comment: @chrylis I kindly disagree ;) We're so used to imperative programming, that any other way sounds too exotic. Imagine if reality was the other way round: we are very used to functional programming and a new imperative paradigm is added to Java. Would you say that this would be the classic case for streams, predicates and optionals?

Comment: Don't call `get()` here!  You have no idea whether its empty or not.  You'll throw an exception if the element was not there.  Instead, use one of the safe methods like ifPresent, orElse, orElseGet, or orElseThrow.

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner Probably a matter of taste. But I also would propose not to combine both. When I see some code getting a value using streams I normally assume that the operations in the stream are free of side-effects. Mixing in removing the element might result in code that can be missleading to readers.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you want to remove all the elements in the `list` for which the `Predicate` is true or only the first (of a possibly zero, one or many elements)?

Comment: @FedericoPeraltaSchaffner It has nothing to do with style preference; I am a fan of lambdas, either Java 8 or Groovy. But in this case, the iteration API provides an efficient operation that can't be used in a stream. It's just an API wart.

Comment: @chrylis I agree with you :) In this case, it's better to loop and use an iterator to remove the element. But you could also filter the stream negating the predicate and collect the results to a new list. Both are valid, both have cons and pros. Anyways, I'd use an iterator.

Comment: @Kedar Mhaswade The first you said: I want to remove the elements matching the predicate **but** I also know that the list will contain only one element with a given "pod".

Comment: Well, not only one, but at most one (and hence use `Optional`). Sorry insist to be precise, but it is needed, IMO. In this case, you should just take @chrylis's advice because _mutating_ a list of things is not _functional_. So, it's appropriate to use the existing "remove while iterating" Java pattern (ensuring that Iterator supports removal) rather than trying to fit this in the Lambda/Stream regime.

Answer (score 235):

**To Remove element from the list**

```
objectA.removeIf(x -> conditions);
```

eg:

```
objectA.removeIf(x -> blockedWorkerIds.contains(x));

List<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
str1.add("A");
str1.add("B");
str1.add("C");
str1.add("D");

List<String> str2 = new ArrayList<String>();
str2.add("D");
str2.add("E");

str1.removeIf(x -> str2.contains(x)); 

str1.forEach(System.out::println);
```

**OUTPUT:**
A
B
C

Comment: i'd suggest this as the best answer

Comment: This is very neat. You might need to implement the equals/hashCode if this is not done for your own objects. (In this example String is used which have them by default).

Comment: IMHO the answer does not consider the "get" part: `removeIf` is an elegant solution to remove elements from a collection, but it does not return the removed element.

Comment: Its a very simple mode to exclude an object from java ArrayList. Thkns a lot. Work fine to me.

Comment: FYI removeIf has time complexity O(n). Source: https://www.javabrahman.com/java-8/java-8-collection-removeif-method-tutorial-with-examples/

Comment: This does not answer the question. The requirement is to remove the element from the list and and get removed item/items to a new list.

Answer (score 42):

Although the thread is quite old, still thought to provide solution - using `Java8`.

Make the use of `removeIf` function. Time complexity is `O(n)`

```
producersProcedureActive.removeIf(producer -> producer.getPod().equals(pod));
```

API reference: [removeIf docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

Assumption: `producersProcedureActive` is a `List`

**NOTE: With this approach you won't be able to get the hold of the deleted item.**

Comment: Additionally to deleting the element from the list, the OP still wants a reference to the element.

Comment: @eee: Thanks a lot for pointing that out. I missed that part from OP's original question.

Comment: just to note this will remove all the item which matches to the condition. But OP seems need to remove only the first item (OP  used findFirst() )

Comment: @asifsid88 how do you get removed element? Isn't the title "get and remove"?

Answer (score 26):

Consider using vanilla java iterators to perform the task:

```
public static <T> T findAndRemoveFirst(Iterable<? extends T> collection, Predicate<? super T> test) {
    T value = null;
    for (Iterator<? extends T> it = collection.iterator(); it.hasNext();)
        if (test.test(value = it.next())) {
            it.remove();
            return value;
        }
    return null;
}
```

**Advantages**:

1. It is plain and obvious.
2. It traverses only once and only up to the matching element.
3. You can do it on any `Iterable` even without `stream()` support *(at least those implementing `remove()` on their iterator)*.

**Disadvantages**:

1. You cannot do it in place as a single expression (auxiliary method or variable required)

---

As for the

> Is it possible to combine get and remove in a lambda expression?

other answers clearly show that it is possible, but you should be aware of

1. Search and removal may traverse the list twice
2. `ConcurrentModificationException` may be thrown when removing element from the list being iterated

Comment: I like this solution, but note that it has one serious disadvantage you missed: many Iterable implementations have `remove()` methods that throw UOE.  (Not the ones for JDK collections, of course, but I think its unfair to say "works on any Iterable".)

Comment: I think we could assume that if an element can be removed *in general*, it can be removed *by iterator*

Comment: You could assume that, but having looked at hundred of iterator implementations, it would be a bad assumption.  (I still like the approach; you're just over-selling it.)

Comment: @Brian Goetz: the `default` implementation of `removeIf` makes the same assumption, but, of course, it’s defined on `Collection` rather than `Iterable`…

Answer (score 21):

The direct solution would be to invoke [`ifPresent(consumer)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) on the Optional returned by [`findFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--). This consumer will be invoked when the optional is not empty. The benefit also is that it won't throw an exception if the find operation returned an empty optional, like your current code would do; instead, nothing will happen.

If you want to return the removed value, you can `map` the `Optional` to the result of calling `remove`:

```
producersProcedureActive.stream()
                        .filter(producer -> producer.getPod().equals(pod))
                        .findFirst()
                        .map(p -> {
                            producersProcedureActive.remove(p);
                            return p;
                        });
```

But note that the [`remove(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-java.lang.Object-) operation will again traverse the list to find the element to remove. If you have a list with random access, like an `ArrayList`, it would be better to make a Stream over the indexes of the list and find the first index matching the predicate:

```
IntStream.range(0, producersProcedureActive.size())
         .filter(i -> producersProcedureActive.get(i).getPod().equals(pod))
         .boxed()
         .findFirst()
         .map(i -> producersProcedureActive.remove((int) i));
```

With this solution, the [`remove(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove-int-) operation operates directly on the index.

Comment: I think we can ignore the cost of boxing one single `int` value…

Comment: This is pathological for a linked list.

Comment: @chrylis The index solution would be indeed. Depending on the list implementation, one would prefer one over the other. Made a small edit.

Comment: @chrylis: in case of a `LinkedList` you perhaps shouldn’t use the stream API as there is no solution without traversing at least twice. But I don’t know of any real life scenario where the academic advantage of a linked list can compensate its actual overhead. So the simple solution is to never use `LinkedList`.

Comment: Oh so many edits… now the first solution doesn’t provide the removed element as `remove(Object)` only returns a `boolean` telling whether there was an element to remove or not.

Comment: Is it OK to remove the element from the list inside the `Optional.map()` operation? I know it works, but shouldn't functions be used to produce a result from its input?

Comment: @Tunaki Why do I need the `boxed()` method to cast the mapper to int?

Comment: @Marco Stramezzi: unfortunately, the comment explaining it got removed. Without `boxed()` you get an `OptionalInt` which can only `map` from `int` to `int`. Unlike `IntStream`, there is no `mapToObj` method. With `boxed()`, you’ll get an `Optional<Integer>` which allows to `map` to an arbitrary object, i.e. the `ProducerDTO` returned by `remove(int)`. The cast from `Integer` to `int` is necessary to disambiguate between `remove(int)` and `remove(Object)`.

Comment: I really like this. You just need to choose an appropriate underlying list. For me, I use a HashSet there. Functionality and performance are satisfactory.

Answer (score 12):

Use can use filter of Java 8, and create another list if you don't want to change the old list:

```
List<ProducerDTO> result = producersProcedureActive
                            .stream()
                            .filter(producer -> producer.getPod().equals(pod))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure this will be an unpopular answer, but it works...

```
ProducerDTO[] p = new ProducerDTO[1];
producersProcedureActive
            .stream()
            .filter(producer -> producer.getPod().equals(pod))
            .findFirst()
            .ifPresent(producer -> {producersProcedureActive.remove(producer); p[0] = producer;}
```

`p[0]` will either hold the found element or be null.

The "trick" here is circumventing the "effectively final" problem by using an *array* reference that is effectively final, but setting its first element.

Comment: It this case, it’s not that bad, but not an improvement over the possibility to just call `.orElse(null)` to get the `ProducerDTO` or `null`…

Comment: In that case, it might be easier to just have `.orElse(null)` and have an `if`, no?

Comment: @Holger but how can you invoke `remove()` too by using `orElse(null)`?

Comment: Just use the result. `if(p!=null) producersProcedureActive.remove(p);` that’s still shorter than the lambda expression in your `ifPresent` call.

Comment: @holger I interpreted the goal of the question as being avoiding multiple statements - ie a 1-line solution

Comment: @Bohemian: I always find the stretching of the term “one line” very funny. Your posted code spans six lines, however, if we interpret “one line” as “one statement”, you still don’t have that as you need the array declaration, plus the stream statement, plus the expression to extract the actual value from the array. I don’t see how this is less than a single stream statement, followed by a single `if` statement.

Answer (score 4):

With [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can use `detectIndex` along with `remove(int)` on any java.util.List.

```
List<Integer> integers = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int index = Iterate.detectIndex(integers, i -> i > 2);
if (index > -1) {
    integers.remove(index);
}

Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 4, 5), integers);
```

If you use the [`MutableList`](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/7.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/list/MutableList.html) type from Eclipse Collections, you can call the `detectIndex` method directly on the list.

```
MutableList<Integer> integers = Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
int index = integers.detectIndex(i -> i > 2);
if (index > -1) {
    integers.remove(index);
}

Assert.assertEquals(Lists.mutable.with(1, 2, 4, 5), integers);
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, this might be a use case for loops and iterables. In my opinion, this is the simplest approach. If you want to modify the list in-place, it cannot be considered "real" functional programming anyway. But you could use `Collectors.partitioningBy()` in order to get a new list with elements which satisfy your condition, and a new list of those which don't. Of course with this approach, if you have multiple elements satisfying the condition, all of those will be in that list and not only the first.

Comment: Much better to filter the stream and collect results to a new list

Answer (score 2):

The below logic is the solution without modifying the original list

```
List<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
str1.add("A");
str1.add("B");
str1.add("C");
str1.add("D");

List<String> str2 = new ArrayList<String>();
str2.add("D");
str2.add("E");

List<String> str3 = str1.stream()
                        .filter(item -> !str2.contains(item))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

str1 // ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
str2 // ["D", "E"]
str3 // ["A", "B", "C"]
```

Answer (score 2):

When we want to **get multiple elements from a List into a new list (filter using a predicate) and remove them from the existing list**, I could not find a proper answer anywhere.

Here is how we can do it using Java Streaming API partitioning.

```
Map<Boolean, List<ProducerDTO>> classifiedElements = producersProcedureActive
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(producer -> producer.getPod().equals(pod)));

// get two new lists 
List<ProducerDTO> matching = classifiedElements.get(true);
List<ProducerDTO> nonMatching = classifiedElements.get(false);

// OR get non-matching elements to the existing list
producersProcedureActive = classifiedElements.get(false);
```

This way you effectively remove the filtered elements from the original list and add them to a new list.

Refer the *5.2. Collectors.partitioningBy* section of [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/java-collection-remove-elements).

Answer (score 1):

the task is: get ✶*and*✶ remove element from list

```
p.stream().collect( Collectors.collectingAndThen( Collector.of(
    ArrayDeque::new,
    (a, producer) -> {
      if( producer.getPod().equals( pod ) )
        a.addLast( producer );
    },
    (a1, a2) -> {
      return( a1 );
    },
    rslt -> rslt.pollFirst()
  ),
  (e) -> {
    if( e != null )
      p.remove( e );  // remove
    return( e );    // get
  } ) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
resumoRemessaPorInstrucoes.removeIf(item -> 
            item.getTipoOcorrenciaRegistro() == TipoOcorrenciaRegistroRemessa.PEDIDO_PROTESTO.getNome() ||
            item.getTipoOcorrenciaRegistro() == TipoOcorrenciaRegistroRemessa.SUSTAR_PROTESTO_BAIXAR_TITULO.getNome());
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Combining my initial idea and your answers I reached what seems to be the solution
to my own question:

```
public ProducerDTO findAndRemove(String pod) {
    ProducerDTO p = null;
    try {
        p = IntStream.range(0, producersProcedureActive.size())
             .filter(i -> producersProcedureActive.get(i).getPod().equals(pod))
             .boxed()
             .findFirst()
             .map(i -> producersProcedureActive.remove((int)i))
             .get();
        logger.debug(p);
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        logger.error("No producer found with POD [" + pod + "]");
    }
    return p;
}
```

It lets remove the object using `remove(int)` that do not traverse again the 
list (as suggested by @Tunaki) **and** it lets return the removed object to
the function caller.

I read your answers that suggest me to choose safe methods like `ifPresent` instead of `get` but I do not find a way to use them in this scenario.

Are there any important drawback in this kind of solution?

**Edit following @Holger advice**

This should be the function I needed

```
public ProducerDTO findAndRemove(String pod) {
    return IntStream.range(0, producersProcedureActive.size())
            .filter(i -> producersProcedureActive.get(i).getPod().equals(pod))      
            .boxed()                                                                
            .findFirst()
            .map(i -> producersProcedureActive.remove((int)i))
            .orElseGet(() -> {
                logger.error("No producer found with POD [" + pod + "]"); 
                return null; 
            });
}
```

Comment: You should not use `get` and catch the exception. That’s not only bad style but may also cause bad performance. The clean solution is even simpler, `return /* stream operation*/.findFirst()  .map(i -> producersProcedureActive.remove((int)i)) .orElseGet(() -> { logger.error("No producer found with POD [" + pod + "]"); return null; });`

Answer (score 0):

A variation of the above:

```
    import static java.util.function.Predicate.not;

    final Optional<MyItem> myItem = originalCollection.stream().filter(myPredicate(someInfo)).findFirst();
    final List<MyItem> myOtherItems = originalCollection.stream().filter(not(myPredicate(someInfo))).toList();

    private Predicate<MyItem> myPredicate(Object someInfo) {
        return myItem -> myItem.someField() == someInfo;
    }
```