# Cannot remove element from an Array List

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Some background: I am new to Java and am taking a basic java class.  I am currently on the final project for the class and completed everything except for this last bit of code.  For some reason, I am having the toughest time deleting an element from an array list.  Here is the code I am working on:

```
public static void delete(String bookID) {
    for (book eachElement : catalog) {
        if (eachElement.getBookID().equals(bookID)) {
            catalog.remove(eachElement);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

code executes, no run time errors but it won't delete anything.
also, I know everything works prior to the remove statement because I have another method that computes calculations using the same exact for and if statement with a select bookID string.

Comment: it won't delete anything - maybe because there is no element with arg bookId?

Comment: You should check if your bookID really is equal to one of the IDs in the list, including case etc. Use a debugger for that. But once you do that - you'll get a concurrent update exception, because you should only be able to remove from a list while iterating it, if you use that list's iterator (explicitly).

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701337/java-8-lambda-get-and-remove-element-from-list)

Comment: @RealSkeptic  He should be fine since it `returns` after removing it (although it's not good practise).

Comment: @SteveSmith that's implementation specific. Better be avoided.

Comment: Use Iterator instead of for loop on collections if you want to modify elements in the collection.

Comment: Since this is a static method it means your `catalog` is also static, are your sure it has not been updated somewhere else in the code?

Answer (score 5):

You need to use iterator, otherwise you will get [java.util.ConcurrentModificationException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html)

```
public static void delete(String bookID) {
    for (Iterator<Book> it = catalog.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
        Book book = it.next();
        if (book.getBookID().equalsIgnoreCase(bookID)) {
            it.remove(book);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) is used to discard case differences.

`java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown, because you are doing 2 operations on the list: **iteration** and **removal**. So, actually, there is another approach - *copy the list on each step of iteration*.

```
public static void delete(String bookID) {
    for (Book book : new ArrayList<>(catalog)) {
        if (book.getBookID().equalsIgnoreCase(bookID)) {
            catalog.remove(book);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: Because of performance considerations (quadratic memory usage and linear removal on each step), I don't recommend the last approach. I give this example only to stress out the underlying reason why `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown.

Comment: There is no need to use different logic for duplicates. Just remove the `return` from the first loop and it will remove any and all duplicates without iterating the list twice.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 5):

You should not and cannot remove an Element from a Collection while being in a forEach loop.

Please read the Documentation for ArrayList in Java.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

There you actually can see, that ArrayList.remove(Object o), removes o if it is in the list, so your method is not needed.

So the answer is, find the book Object with your ID and then remove it. Or better use a Map to store your data.

In your case it would be

```
Book b = null;
for(Book book : books) {
     if(book.getBookId().equals(bookId)) {
         b = book.getBookId();
         break;
     }
}
books.remove(b);
```

Or if you are into Java8 which you really should be :D

```
books.stream().filter(b -> b.getBookId().equals(bookId)).getFirst().ifPresent(books::remove);
```

Comment: @RealSkeptic sry my bad, fixed it. Btw nice name :D

Comment: Good. So now there are no logic problems. But you're still iterating the list twice, which is not necessary.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I am not, the remove is the second one that's true, however there is not other way, unless you remove by index, however thats not much better either. using this data store type and parameter. Thats why i really recommend using a Map, or even a Set and use Book parameter instead of a String.

Comment: No, you can remove using the iterator. See answer by Zgurskyi.

Comment: I liked the stream answer +1

Answer (score 2):

Removal of elements, while an iterator is being used, is undefined.The better approach would be to use removeIf.

```
 catalog.removeIf(eachElement -> eachElement.getBookID().equals(bookId));
```

Comment: Nice, but since OP returns after removal of the element, if the list contains duplicates the logic is different.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iterator in order to delete item while using loop .
also double check if the id exist (make some System.out.println("test") and check if it is entering the scope).