# How to filter lines from a file by multiple values?

Tags: java

I have a file and I need to filter all lines that contain a string from a list of strings.

Can you please suggest how to do this without reopening the file every time I filter by a value?

This is what I have:

```
for (String str : lines){
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileToRead))) {
        filteredLines.addAll(br.lines().filter(line -> line.contains(str)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

I tried solutions from simular questions, but I was unable to make it work.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to apply filter like if any string is found in the line, use `anyMatch` like below. If you want all strings must be present in line, replace it with `allMatch`.

```
    List<String> keywords = Arrays.asList("my", "key", "word");

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileToRead"))) {
        //this is the filtered lines
        List<String> filteredLine = br.lines()
            .filter(line -> keywords.stream().anyMatch(line::contains))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

        String fileName = "c://sampleFile.txt";

        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {

            List<String> filteredLines = stream.filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // handle exception
        }

    }
```

Comment: Im sorry I've somehow missed to add the first line to my code: for (String str : list) . So my question is how can I filter the lines by all values in the list?

Answer (score 0):

maybe next will help you
[To Remove element from the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35701337/java-8-lambda-get-and-remove-element-from-list)