# Could we remove while iterating if we just remove 1 element?

Tags: java, list, collections

I have a list of custom objects. I need to get/remove a specific object from that list but the `equals` implemented would not work based on what I need to search.
The following would work:

```
int index = -1;  
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  if(list.get(i).getAttr().equals(arg)) {
     index = i;  
     break;  
  }  
}    
CustomObject = list.remove(index);  
// use CustomObject here
```

I was wondering if I could do the `list.remove` inside the `for` loop despite not using an `iterator` since the loop breaks immediately

Comment: might wanna consider this https://stackoverflow.com/a/45935707/10416835

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: @Michael: Because since `list` is passed as an interface, I don't want to do a solution that would work for e.g. the `ArrayList` at that version of java

Comment: Ok, then what is stopping you from trying with, say, the 4 main List implementations, and using those findings as a basis for your question?

Comment: Yes. You could also use `list.removeIf((a)->a.getAttr().equals(arg));` however this would remove all the elements satisfying the condition instead of just the first.

Comment: @Michael: I thought that when we code against an interface the whole idea is that we don't write any code that depends on the concrete implementation at any point in time. Isn't what you are suggesting essentially that? Apologies if I misunderstood your point

Comment: I'm suggesting conducting a test to see what happens. In which case the exact structure is irrelevant provided it gives you the information you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Using the `delete(int)` method in your loop will work just fine.

Your loop is closed so you have full control on `i` and you can use the list as you please. You don't use `i` after having deleted the first element that matches, so there are no caveat. If you were to reuse it, you would have to *not* increment it.

To avoid any trouble, the following if both more readable and expressive. Also, it's totally implementation-agnostic.

```
CustomObject deletedObject = null;
for (Iterator<CustomObject> i = list.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
  CustomObject candidate = i.next();
  if (candidate.getAttr().equals(arg)) {
    deletedObject = candidate;
    i.remove();
    break;
  }
}
if (deletedObject != null) {
  // Do something with deletedObject
}
```

Comment: I would also need another variable right? Since I can't do `object = i.remove()` as I can do if I do `object = list.remove(index)`

Comment: @Jim Correct. I updated the answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

There is no special program state associated with “being inside a for loop”. What matters, are the *actions* your program performs.

So

```
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.get(i).getAttr().equals(arg)) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
CustomObject o = list.remove(index);
// use CustomObject here
```

is identical to

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    if(list.get(i).getAttr().equals(arg)) {
        CustomObject o = list.remove(i);
        // use CustomObject here
        break;
    }
}
```

as it performs the same actions (letting aside that the first variant will throw when no match has been found). The differences regarding local variables defined in these code snippets are, well, *local* and do not affect anything outside the containing method.

That said, the rule that you must not modify a collection (except through the iterator) while iterating over it, applies to iterator-based loops, where you are not in control of the iterator’s internal state. When you are using an index based loop and fully understand the implications of removing an object at a particular index (of a random access list), you can even continue iterating. The important aspects, to do it correctly, are that the indices of all subsequent elements decrease by one when removing an element, further the size decreases so you must either, reread the size or decrement a previously cached size value.

E.g., the following loop is valid

```
for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {// rereads size on each iteration
    if(list.get(i).getAttr().equals(arg)) {
        CustomObject o = list.remove(i--); // decrease index after removal
        // use CustomObject here
        // continue
    }
}
```

But, of course, it’s more idiomatic to use an `Iterator` or `removeIf`, as these approaches are not only easier to handle, they also work with other collections than random access lists. And especially `removeIf` may be more efficient when you remove more than one element.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way using streams,

```
    List<String> str1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    str1.add("A");
    str1.add("B");
    str1.add("D");
    str1.add("D");

    Optional<Object> foundVal = str1.stream().filter(s -> 
            s.contains("D")).findFirst().map(val -> {
                                             str1.remove(val);
                                             return val;
                                             });


    System.out.println(str1);
    System.out.print(" " + foundVal.get());

Output

[A, B, D]  D
```